# Redshift - Filtering text with apostrophe

Tags: amazon-redshift, apostrophe

I am trying to see how we can query a text that has an apostrophe.

For example

```
select * from table where name = 'People's'
```

I am trying to query to filter out rows that have `name = People's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redshift, just use 2 consecutive '

so, in your example use

```
select * from table where name = 'People''s'
```